# When trying to clone a repository I get the following message 'tilde_expand_filename: No such user .' and the clone operation failed

Tags: clone, bitbucket

Once I try to clone my git repository through SSH I get the message 'tilde_expand_filename: No such user .' and 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository'. The error message is not clear though.

Answer (score 13):

I checked the configuration file located in the ssh folder `~/.ssh/` and noticed that for some reason the path to the IdentifyFile was incorrect `~./.ssh/id_rsa_mpk` (with an additional dot after the tilde).

I just corrected the path by `~/.ssh/id_rsa_macpro`, and the git clone command worked properly.